# Create a Nested/Repeating field using SQL in BigQuery which can be queried with dot notation (without UNNEST)

Tags: arrays, json, struct, google-bigquery

I am trying to build a data structure in BigQuery using SQL which exactly reflects the data structure which I obtain when uploading JSON.   This will enable me to query the view using SQL with dot notation instead of having to UNNEST, which I do understand but many of my clients find extremely confusing and unintuitive.

If I build a really simple dummy dataset with a couple of rows and then nest using the ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT([field list])) pattern:

```
    WITH
      flat_table AS (
      SELECT "BigQuery" AS name, 23 AS user_count, "Data Warehouse" AS data_thing, 5 AS ease_of_use, "Awesome" AS description UNION ALL
      SELECT "MySQL" AS name, 12 AS user_count, "Database" AS data_thing, 3 AS ease_of_use, "Solid" AS description
      )

    SELECT 
    name, user_count, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(data_thing, ease_of_use, description)) AS attributes
    FROM flat_table 
    GROUP BY name, user_count
```

Then saving and viewing the schema shows that the `attributes` field is `Type = RECORD` and `Mode = REPEATED`.  Schema field names are:

```
name                    
    user_count              
    attributes          
    attributes.data_thing   
    attributes.ease_of_use  
    attributes.description
```

If I look at the COLUMN information in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS query I can see that the `attributes` field `is_nullable = NO`  and `data_type = ARRAY<STRUCT<data_thing STRING, ease_of_use INT64, description STRING>>`

If I want to query this structure I need to use the UNNEST pattern as below:

```
    SELECT
      name,
      user_count
    FROM
      nested_table,
      UNNEST(attributes)
    WHERE
      ease_of_use > 3
```

However when I upload the following JSON representation of the same data to BigQuery with automatic schema detection:

```
    {"attributes":{"description":"Awesome","ease_of_use":5,"data_thing":"Data Warehouse"},"user_count":23,"name":"BigQuery"}
    {"attributes":{"description":"Solid","ease_of_use":3,"data_thing":"Database"},"user_count":12,"name":"MySQL"}
```

The schema looks nearly identical once loaded, except for the `attributes` field is `Mode = NULLABLE` (it is still `Type = RECORD`). The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS shows me that the `attributes` field is now `is_nullable = YES`  and `data_type = STRUCT<data_thing STRING, ease_of_use INT64, description STRING>`, i.e. now nullable and not in an array.

However the most interesting thing for me is that I can now query this table using dot notation instead of the UNNEST pattern, so the query above becomes:

```
    SELECT
      name,
      user_count
    FROM
      nested_table_json
    WHERE
      attributes.ease_of_use > 3
```

Which is arguably easier to read, even in this trivial case.  However once we get to more complex data structures with multiple nested fields and multi-level nesting, the UNNEST pattern becomes extremely difficult to write, QA and debug.  The dot notation pattern appears to be much more intuitive and scalable.

So my question is: is it possible to build a data structure equivalent to the loaded JSON by writing queries in SQL, enabling us to build Standard SQL queries using dot notation and not requiring complex UNNEST patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your array_agg will produce one row, you can drop the ARRAY notation like this:

```
SELECT 
    name, user_count, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(data_thing, ease_of_use, description))[offset(0)] AS attributes
```

notice the use of `OFFSET(0)` this way the returned output will be:

```
[
  {
    "name": "BigQuery",
    "user_count": "23",
    "attributes": {
      "data_thing": "Data Warehouse",
      "ease_of_use": "5",
      "description": "Awesome"
    }
  }
]
```

which can be queried using dot notation.

In case you want just to group result in `STRUCT`, you don't need `array_agg`.

```
WITH
      flat_table AS (
      SELECT "BigQuery" AS name, 23 AS user_count, struct("Data Warehouse" AS data_thing, 5 AS ease_of_use, "Awesome" AS description) as attributes UNION ALL
      SELECT "MySQL" AS name, 12 AS user_count, struct("Database" AS data_thing, 3 AS ease_of_use, "Solid" AS description)
      )

    SELECT 
    *
    FROM flat_table
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much.  This is perfect and solves this problem perfectly in exactly 9 characters!  @Pentium10 you are a legend. Thanks.